# li a mouse-over changing images (of sprite image)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the sprite image hover mouse.

li, a tag does not have a special class. too many.

I would like to add only "_on" in existing class i tags.

**html**

```
<ul id="gnb">
<li class="frist mNavi01"><a href="/in01.asp"><i class="icon icon-mNavi01"></i></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="info/in01.asp"><i class="icon icon-mNavi01_01"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="info/in01_1.asp"><i class="icon icon-mNavi01_02"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="info/in01_2.asp"><i class="icon icon-mNavi01_03"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**css**

```
    .icon-mNavi01_01 { //normal
    background-image: url(../img/sprites/header_icons.png);
    background-position: 0px -129px;
    ...
}
.icon-mNavi01_01_on { //hover
     background-image: url(../img/sprites/header_icons.png);
    background-position: -148px -54px;
    ...
}
.icon-mNavi01_02 { //normal
    background-image: url(../img/sprites/header_icons.png);
    background-position: 0px -296px;
    ...
}
.icon-mNavi01_02_on { //hover
    background-image: url(../img/sprites/header_icons.png);
    background-position: -328px 0px;
    ...
}
.icon-mNavi01_03 { //normal
    background-image: url(../img/sprites/header_icons.png);
    background-position: 0px -53px;
    ...
}
.icon-mNavi01_03_on { //hover
    background-image: url(../img/sprites/header_icons.png);
    background-position: 0px -71px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your question is understandable but you should edit it to be clearer

Comment: you don't need to add _on to classes

Comment: sorry. i can't speak english very well :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:hover` css is used to set style when element is hovered .

```
.icon-mNavi01_01:hover { //hover
     background-image: url(../img/sprites/header_icons.png);
    background-position: -148px -54px;
    ...
}
```